# Boyer - Moore string search into Sunday string search (quick string search) c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, boyer-moore, quick-search

I want to turn my Boyer - Moore algorithm into a Sunday (Quick Search). Currently I have a working version of the Boyer - Moore string search algorithm:

```
vector <int> table(256);
fill(table.begin(), table.end(), -1);

for (int i = 0; i < target_size; i++) {
    table[(int)target[i]] = i;
}

int s = 0;
while (s <= (text_size - target_size)) {
    int j = target_size - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && target[j] == text[s + j]) 
        j--;

    if (j < 0) {
        cout << s << endl;
        s += (s + target_size < text_size) ? text_size- table[text[s + target_size]] : 1;
    }
    else
        s += max(1, j - table[text[s + target_size]]);
}
```

I have been looking at the following 2 links that explain Sunday (Quick search) algorithm, but I am not exactly sure how to change B-M into Sunday:

http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/sundayen.htm

http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node19.html

I would appreciate any tips.